# Αn entire function as an infinite sum of entire functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, entire-functions

Please help me to attack this problem from Complex Analysis:

*Let be $f$ be an entire function, such that $f(0)=0$. Prove that the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f\left(\frac{z}{n^2}\right)$$ defines an entire function.*

Comment: Start by stating the **definition** of "entire function"!

Comment: Perhaps try writing $f(z)$ in terms of its Taylor series at $z=0$ and then see if you can change the order of summation.

Comment: @user247327 "entire function" is a very well known term

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots+a_nz^n+\cdots
$$
and set
$$
g_n(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{z}{n^2}\right).
$$
By virtue of the integral test for series
$$
\sum_{k=m}^n \frac{1}{n^{2j}}<\sum_{k=m}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{2j}}\le \int_{m-1}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{2j}}=\frac{1}{(2j-1)(m-1)^{2j-1}}\le \frac{1}{m-1}.
$$

Let $R>0$ arbitrary, then for $|z|\le R$ and $\,n\ge m>1$, we have
$$
|g_m(z)-g_n(z)|\le \sum_{k=m}^n\left|\,f\left(\frac{z}{k^2}\right)\right|
\le \sum_{k=m}^n \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{|a_j||z|^j}{k^{2j}}\le \frac{1}{m-1} \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_j|R^j.
$$

This implies that the sequence of entire functions $\{g_n(z)\}$ is locally uniformly Cauchy, and hence locally uniformly convergent to an entire function.

Comment: It seems like you have changed the order of summation in $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_kz^k}{n^{2k}}$ without justification to conclude $b_k=a_k\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2k}}$.  If we knew the double sum converged, that wouldn't be a problem.  But how do we know that it does?

Comment: @sharding4 See the newly edited version

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis is their an alternate method of proof ? I would like to attempt this question it seems one can convert $g_n(z)$ into a product and go form there.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that the series converges uniformly on the disk $|z| \le R$ for any $R$.